# TeamCity throws FileNotFoundException trying to load android project

Tags: android, teamcity

I setup a TeamCity server and have it successfully building several C#.NET projects.  Now I'm trying to get it to build a simple Android project but cannot get it to work.  Checking the BuildLog it fails with the following error:

```
[17:00:11][Step 1/1] Using IntelliJ IDEA External Make #141.3028
[17:00:11][Step 1/1] Loading project (2s)
[17:00:13][Step 1/1] C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\system\.jps\c67b7fe19e4788da\-1866084326\gradle\configuration.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
[17:00:13]
[Step 1/1] java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\system\.jps\c67b7fe19e4788da\-1866084326\gradle\configuration.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.JDOMUtil.loadDocument(JDOMUtil.java:337)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.gradle.model.impl.JpsGradleExtensionServiceImpl.getGradleProjectConfiguration(JpsGradleExtensionServiceImpl.java:125)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.gradle.model.impl.JpsGradleExtensionServiceImpl.getGradleProjectConfiguration(JpsGradleExtensionServiceImpl.java:113)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.gradle.model.impl.GradleResourcesTarget.computeRootDescriptors(GradleResourcesTarget.java:69)

    ...
```

The directory `..\-1866084326\` exists but it does not contain a `gradle` subdirectory.

I am not very familiar with the details of building gradle/android projects as I've only ever used AndroidStudio's UI to build.  I have done a lot of searching but have found virtually no information about setting up an android project in TeamCity beyond what is in the TeamCity user docs that effectively says "use IntelliJ IDEA Build Runner".

I setup a build config with an IntelliJ IDEA Project build step.  The project settings are parsed without error and I leave everything the way it was detected.  The only parameters I have are `Android_SDK = C:\Users\%env.USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Android\sdk`, `API_Level = 23`, and `system.path.macro.USER.HOME = %env.HOMEPATH%`.

This is on a Windows 7 x64 Pro server.

I can build the project directly in TeamCity's workdir using AndroidStudio so I expect it is a build runner configuration issue, but I cannot find any search results for this specific error.  Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: One thing I did when building Android source was create a blank file and see what happens - funny thing is some files could be blank anyway. If there's multiple errors, then your probably missing something important - I don't know what though (that's why your doing that and I'm not :-) Also if it goes along happily and everything works after that one file, then just go with it till sometime you finally see the problem.

Comment: Well thats an interesting thought, but it just changes the exception to: `org.jdom.input.JDOMParseException: Error on line 1: Premature end of file.`

Comment: Totally forgot, that the other thing is to search for that file and then put it there. Can't find it? Look elsewhere. It seems the file can't be empty here :-)

However, It is the exact same crash this person has: https://discuss.gradle.org/t/configuration-xml-file-not-recreated-after-deamon-crash/9664

Can't say if that person was even on the right track though.

That's about all the help I can give.

Comment: There's also this: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=183078 Different situation, but same error. You'll have to figure it out from there.

Comment: @CmosBattery Interesting.  The file definitely doesn't exist in the project (and that folder doesn't exist on the build server, though it seems like it should be auto-generated).  I also don't have gradle daemon enabled on the build server.  I suspect this has something to do with the IntelliJ IDEA Runner, as I switched to using the Gradle runner and it compiles.