# Running a project with Gradle and TestNG in TeamCity

Tags: java, gradle, teamcity, testng

Currently I have a TestNG project that uses Gradle for the dependency management. The tests are currently ran using TestNG xml files. I'm using Intellij IDEA 2016.2 for my IDE.

I've tried adding the project to TeamCity in order to get a nightly regression test running for all the TestNG tests in the project, but I can't figure out how to get it to run in TeamCity. I have one build configuration grab the current code from the master branch of the git repo and then build it using Gradle. That one works just fine and without error.

But when I try to add an Intellij IDEA Project build configuration, it fails to compile parts of the project, specifically it won't compile the JOOQ generated code that I use to access a database.

The error(s):

```
C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\3cb51db1f1141a11\src\main\java\org\jooq\db\stage\tables\records\TransferRecordsRecord.java:11: cannot find symbol 
  symbol:   class Field 
  location: package org.jooq 
import org.jooq.Field;
```

And it prints a hundred more of these for various classes in the same library.

And oddly enough, a `FileNotFoundException` is thrown shortly before the compilation errors:

```
[08:47:52] :     [Step 1/1] Loading project
[08:47:53] :     [Step 1/1] C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\system\.jps\3cb51db1f1141a11\1575776824\gradle\configuration.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
[08:47:53] :     [Step 1/1] java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\system\.jps\3cb51db1f1141a11\1575776824\gradle\configuration.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

Which is looking for a `configuration.xml` file in a gradle folder, neither of which exist in the specified path.

I've found a similar post that had the same `FileNotFoundException`, but no solution here: [TeamCity throws FileNotFoundException trying to load android project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37691537/teamcity-throws-filenotfoundexception-trying-to-load-android-project)

I'm new to TeamCity and it seemed fairly straightforward when I started with it, but I'm at a complete lost as to how to get this project up and running in it.

Comment: I am not sure if you really need to use Idea project runner.
Why are you trying to use it, if "Gradle" build step works fine?

Comment: @NikitaSkvortsov Using the Idea project runner because in it's configuration there is an option for `Run Configurations` which allows me to add any number of my TestNG xml tests to the configuration for the run. This way I can have multiple build configurations for different tests, but without clogging up my build.gradle file with a bunch of tasks.

Comment: The IDEA Project runner in TeamCity only uses IDEA's project files for building.
So first, make sure all the project files (`.idea` dir and `*.iml`) are available in version control.
Then try opening the project pointing IDEA to root directory instead of `build.gradle` - this will load idea's model, not the Gradle one and check everything works locally.
If everything is fine, but the build still fails in TeamCity, please post an issue here: youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=TW